Rspec - Uniqueness shouldamatcher failing
I have an ActiveRecord table with a column called name. I need this field to be present and unique. So I have the following specs
it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }

And the corresponding rule in the model is:
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

My factory contains the following:
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :model_name do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Name #{n}" }

    after(:build) do |model|
      pack.rels << build(:relation)
    end
  end
end

The problem is that when I run the specs I get the following error.
Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }
     
     Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord::ValidateUniquenessOfMatcher::ExistingRecordInvalid:
       validate_uniqueness_of works by matching a new record against an
       existing record. If there is no existing record, it will create one
    Mysql2::Error: Field 'name' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `table_name`

What am I doing wrong?

Please add your test -- this looks like an issue with your set up

I added where exactly I got the error, in which test I mean. Also added the factory

Your factory seems wrong - it’s not setting the name value in the table. Hard to tell where you have an error since everything in your examples has generic names.

Did you set subject in your test? e.g. subject {FactoryBot.build(:model_name)}?

This looks to be a problem that could be fixed by adding a database migration to set a default value to null or empty on the db level. Post your schema and migrations for this model
